# What benefits does a DI container provide over a factory?

Tags: dependency-injection, ioc-container

There are many discussions around here about this, but none seem to really answer the question.

I'm currently considering using the [Symfony 2 service container](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/service_container.html). The more I look at it though, the more it seems like I could just do the same thing with a service factory. Consider the following example:

**services.yml**

```
services:
    my_mailer:
        class:        Acme\Mailer
        arguments:    [sendmail]
    newsletter_manager:
        class:     Acme\Newsletter\NewsletterManager
        arguments: [@my_mailer]
```

Now to get a newsletter manager, I do something like:

```
// this has been configured with the above yml file
$serviceContainer = new ServiceContainer();
$newsletterManager = $serviceContainer->get("newsletter_manager");
```

However, consider the following factory style code:

```
class ServiceContainer
{
    public function getMyMailer()
    {
        return new Acme\Mailer("sendmail");
    }

    public function getNewsletterManager()
    {
        return new Acme\Newsletter\NewsletterManager($this->getMyMailer());
    }
}
```

And then using it:

```
$serviceContainer = new ServiceContainer();
$newsletterManager = $serviceContainer->getNewsletterManager();
```

Is there something I'm missing here? Because I don't really see the advantage to using a DI container if a factory can do all of that for me.

I have heard using factories causes your code to "depend on the factory". I either don't understand this argument or the person arguing against factories is confused. Only the top level class (the composition root) would have a reference to the factory, just like it would be the only one with the reference to the DI container.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there something I'm missing here? Because I don't really see the
>   advantage to using a DI container if a factory can do all of that for
>   me.

Yes - you are using your DI container using the [Service Locator (anti-)pattern](http://%20Service%20Locator%20%28anti-%29pattern) instead of injecting your dependencies into your classes. Your class should not have to reference your DI container at all.

Instead there should be just a single aggregate root where you create the container and resolve all dependencies. Once you have resolved your top level class instance all of its dependencies (and the dependencies of the dependencies and so on) are then resolved using the IoC container using the [Hollywood Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_principle) - when class instances are created all of its dependencies are passed in, the instance never asks for a dependency itself.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? The examples are functionally the same. Only the composition root has a reference to the factory, which is the exact same place one would have reference to the DI container from. In neither example are the classes responsible for fulfilling their own dependencies.

Comment: how to you pass in the dependencies of your dependencies using the factory? In other words using an IoC container you can resolve a full graph of dependencies

Comment: A `NewsletterManager` has a dependency of `MyMailer`. When you call `getNewsletterManager()` on the factory, it calls `getMyMailer()` which is *also* on the factory. It is my understanding that the Service Locator pattern would be where I have the `NewsletterManager` resolve its dependencies by itself, in the constructor or something.

Comment: You are right - from the consuming class point of view there is no difference in this particular case, since you hard-coded dependency resolution in your factory - how would this scale though? If tomorrow your `NewsletterManager` class needs another dependency you would have to update your factory - using an IoC container there is no change needed if that other dependency is already resolvable using the container.

Comment: The Symfony 2 DI Container doesn't have any kind of automatic dependency resolution like the .NET ones do, so that part doesn't matter.